# Getting a error while building In netlify (web app using gatsby and strapi)

Tags: npm, gatsby, netlify, strapi

To recreate it you can clone my branch
github link :- https://github.com/WOLFIEEEE/Gatsby-portfolio/tree/trying-heroku-1

and too see the error you can go to link:- https://app.netlify.com/sites/wolfie-portfolio/deploys/5feabd7bb15555000765b2f5

I am deploying My strapi to heroku. When i run my project locally I dont get any error it runs smooth and when I push same thing to github and strapi try to build it is fails .

I am new to this if someone can help me out it would be great help

````
error Failed to retrieve metadata from image /opt/build/repo/src/assets/hero-img.png
10:55:49 AM: 
10:55:49 AM: 
10:55:49 AM:   Error: Input file contains unsupported image format
10:55:49 AM: 
10:55:49 AM: not finished run static queries - 0.053s
10:55:49 AM: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
10:55:49 AM: npm ERR! errno 1
10:55:49 AM: npm ERR! gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0 build: `gatsby build`
10:55:49 AM: npm ERR! Exit status 1
10:55:49 AM: npm ERR!
10:55:49 AM: npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0 build script.
10:55:49 AM: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
10:55:49 AM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
10:55:49 AM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2020-12-29T05_25_49_093Z-debug.log
10:55:49 AM: ​
10:55:49 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
10:55:49 AM:   "build.command" failed                                        
10:55:49 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
10:55:49 AM: ​
10:55:49 AM:   Error message
10:55:49 AM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build
10:55:49 AM: ​
10:55:49 AM:   Error location
10:55:49 AM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
10:55:49 AM:   npm run build ```

this is the error I got you can check above netlify link for more info
````

Comment: I already tried  "resolutions": {
    "sharp": "0.24.0"
  },   which was shown in an closed issue of gatsby regarding Image but it didn;t do much help

Comment: Does it build locally?

Comment: yes it did build

Answer (score 0):

Look at:

> 6:25:49 AM:   Error: Input file contains unsupported image format

In your [`gatsby-config.js`(line 7)](https://github.com/WOLFIEEEE/Gatsby-portfolio/blob/trying-heroku-1/gatsby-config.js#L7) you are using an image:

```
image: "/rrrrrr.png",
```

The image that you are pointing to in the [static folder](https://github.com/WOLFIEEEE/Gatsby-portfolio/tree/trying-heroku-1/static) is named `rrrrrrr.PNG` (notice the format, `.PNG` instead of `.png`).

In addition, that image is outside the ecosystem of Gatsby since it won't be parsed and transformed by Gatsby's transformers and sharps and therefore, it won't be available to use as `gatsby-image`, but since the path will exist, you will be able to use it as a normal image using `img` tag.

Look carefully at your logs. Your issue has gone but now, the issue is:

> 8:45:44 AM: error There was an error in your GraphQL query:
>
> 8:45:44 AM: Cannot query field "childImageSharp" on type "StrapiAboutImage".

I don't know what image it is this but it seems to be unparsed by Gatsby. To allow Gatsby to use `childImageSharp`, the image must be in the ecosystem of Gatsby to be parseable by transformers and sharps dependencies.

In your [`/pages/about.js` (line 59)](https://github.com/WOLFIEEEE/Gatsby-portfolio/blob/trying-heroku-1/src/pages/about.js#L59):

```
Image {
  childImageSharp {
    fluid {
      src
    }
  }
```

This is causing your issue. Without knowing your data structure it's impossible to guess what's causing the error but apparently, Gatsby is not able to parse that image using `childImageSharp`.

Comment: Thnaks for spotting these I changed them . but building still shows error

Comment: I still see the wrong format commited. Try removing that line of the `gatsby-node.js` to ensure that the issue comes from there.

Comment: update first i remove the img and its related tags and all then it was throwing a error and then I removed the whole seo file which was quering that image then also its showing error I don't know what problem probably look into it after my exam is over I have a exam in 30 min .  You can look into the github link i updated the changes will provide netlify link of what error i was getting  [link](https://app.netlify.com/sites/wolfie-portfolio/deploys/5feade3d0e442e000759d9f9)

Comment: Look carefully at your logs @KhushwantParihar . The issue is completely different now and not "also showing error". Your question bug has been fixed, now you have another issue related to your about page. I've updated the answer but in this case, the issue belongs to Strapi and your data structure.

Comment: Thank's for help buddy will try to fix it . But i keep getting confused the project is buuilding just time locally but it's showing error when I use heroku api to fetch data

Comment: Usually when having different behaviors locally vs Netlify's side, is due to mismatching versions of Node between those environments. You can set those versions in different ways. If the issue persists will try this approach.

Comment: childImageSharp Is only throwing error when I use heroku Url for developing the site . [link](https://github.com/WOLFIEEEE/Gatsby-portfolio/blob/trying-heroku-1/gatsby-config.js) it's to link to gatsby config when I change my api Url to localhost It's working file but at the same it throws error when I try to do with heroku url . will share strapi github in a minute .

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was in the uploading service as Heroku refresh every 2-3 hours or a day the data we provided to it get lost.

Check if the Upload server is working fine or not.